# Get URL parameters & values with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, parameters, parameter-passing

How to pass the values from one page to other page using the url in jquery.

I got few examples from google, below is my code but not able to pass the values.

Can any one help me on this ?

Comment: **'below is my code'** .... not able to see it..????

Comment: When I paste the code, I am not able to post.

Comment: try to paste code with proper formatting.

Answer (score 1):

This is the function I always use in my work

```
function getParameterByName(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results == null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

from an [SO answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript). Please note that you don't need to use jquery for this.

To use it:

Given a URL

```
http://www.example.com?testParam=value
```

get its value by

```
var myVal = getparameterByName("testParam");
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: I am trying with this code :

http://jquery-howto.blogspot.ie/2009/09/get-url-parameters-values-with-jquery.html

Comment: Post your code and the part of the code that doesn't work. I'll help from there.

Comment: Thanks Kuma &  Kartikeya , I got the result. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please don't forget to upvote and choose as best answer if it helped you :)